# How long does the jquery .ready() function wait?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a page on which php will output a rather big div, which has lots of components inside it. The JS to handle that div begins almost instantaneously, but there are problems of timing related to loading of bigDiv and script that handles it.

So, I applied a code like this to handle it on ready()

```
var bigDiv = $(document).find('#bigDiv');
bigDiv.ready(function{
    //some code here
});
```

Now my question is, if `bigDiv` takes a long time to appear, how long does `ready()` function wait? What if `bigDiv` does not appear at all?

So to avoid the script waiting for it, I applied a timeout,

Thus I chose another approach like this:

```
var waitTimer = 0;
var lodTmout  = 2000;
function chkDataLod(){
    var bigDiv = $pH(document).find('#bigDiv');
    if(bigDiv.length > 0){//find if bigDiv has content
        bigDiv.ready(function(){//wait for bigDiv to load it's contents completely
            //some code here
        });

    }else{
        //chk for bigDiv after every 500 msec for 2000 msec
        if(waitTimer === lodTmout){
            return false;
        }else{
            waitTimer += 500; 
            setTimeout('chkDataLod();',500);
        }      
    }
};

function _init(){
    chkDataLod();
}

_init();
```

Initially I tried to see if bigDiv's content length is more than zero. The problem occured when 'incompletely loaded' bigDiv was being displayed. So I again added the  `.ready()` function. I have some animation functions on that bigDiv which I don't want to initiate until it is completely loaded.

This `bigDiv` is loaded from CDN so load timings are varying. One day it took almost 5 seconds for it to load. Seeing my own approach I know it has problems. I am using setTimeout and ready, both. But I am unsure of how ling ready waits. I tried to see it's documentation but couldn't find it clearly.

How can I solve this for the specified situation??

Comment: This div is being loaded via ajax? I'm not clear on why you don't just use jquery document.ready to handle this.

Comment: "$(document).ready(function () {});" may start after all your page control has created. But if you are talking about browser rendering its another story.

Comment: @kinakuta - I can't use document.ready(), because I want to show bigDiv as soon as IT is loaded. I can't wait for entire page to load, as it might take too much time.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to run your code just after the closing tag of your element.
Like this

```
<div id='bigDiv>....</div>
<script>
// do whatever you want to do with div
</script>
```

ps: or you may try to access any element after the div with some interval. if it exists - your div is ready.

Comment: I was going to say the same thing, and add that if $('#bigDiv') is already returning a non-empty set, then you are unlikely to need to wait for ready().  The only time you need ready() is to make sure that $('#bigDiv') succeeds, and it's better to rearrange your page so the script is below the element (or below the </body> tag, ideally)

Comment: This solution is currently not within scope of my problem. Whatever I must do with bigDiv needs to be contained within js file that I am attaching. So two things happen and they may happen asynchronously. 1. Loading of bigDiv data 2. Loading of js to handle big div data. Now this js that I am including is not related only to bigDiv, it has other functions as well. I got that cleared, because you might doubt why I am putting js separately.

Comment: @Shades88  it is not really clear what your problem is. Until the browser gets the closing tag of the div, jQuery will return empty selection, because element is not in the DOM structure. So all that you need is to check regularly the availability of the required element. Even without ready function.

Comment: Are you trying to do something after an Ajax call returns?  Then you need to look at the Deferred API.  get(url).done(fillBigDiv).done(doSomethingElse)

Comment: @Cheery: yes, I need to regularly check availability of bigDiv, but according to documentation of ready(), it waits till dom is loaded. So I tried `bigDivObj.ready();`, but will it work that way ?

Comment: @Shades88      if you are able to address to the element - it is already loaded. I mean if all the time you were not taking about ajax or any other analogous things to put content into div. If the page is loading, the element will not be available until the closing tag is transferred to the browser.

Comment: @Cheery, so bigDiv object will contain nothing until it is fully loaded?

Comment: @Shades88      Sorry, I think I'm wrong. I just simulated the slow output with sleep() and flush() in php - yes, div is available even when it is not finished, and yes, ready event fires when the page is completed. Let me think a little bit about it :)

Comment: @Shades88      The only idea that comes to mind is to check to length of the content inside, assuming that at list one byte will be transferred within the check period. Something like this (you may also clear interval on document ready).
var timer = setInterval(function(){
    $('#bigDiv').each(function(){
       if ($(this).html().length>len) len = $(this).html().length;
       else
       {
         clearInterval(timer); alert('Ready');     
       } 
    });
}, 500), len = 0;

Answer (score 0):

It depend on how fast is the client internet is, how big is the content in bigDiv, and how fast is the client computer.

Comment: It means what? I know that client internet speed can be slow, that's why this question that I have asked.

Answer (score 0):

try to add at very first line of script tag

```
var d = new Date();  console.log(d.getTime());
```

add same thing after jquery ready function and see

compair this time with page load time

and you will notic that ASA the last image load it run the very next milisecond

Comment: so that means, if my content is never loaded, my page will hang, because ready is checking it continuously ??

Comment: if your content never loaded then even your jquery will never load
i have not seen where my content din't load and my css and javascript files loaded

Comment: no no, my js comes separately and div contents come separately. It is not the case that if my div contents don't come then my js and css have not come.